# Integrated SendGrid SMTP service, getting blank mail on Yahoo and Yopmail but receiving complete mail on Gmail, Hotmail and Rediff

Tags: gmail, message, yahoo, sendgrid

I have integrated SendGrid service in one of the application with unsubscribe message enabled,but while sending emails we are getting complete emails (ie with the text we have put) only for Gmail, Hotmail and Rediff mail but for Yopmail and Yahoo, mails are going blank only with unsubscribe message coming on bottom.We have disabled the unsubscribe option also but then the mail is coming complete blank in Yopmail and Yahoo.

One more thing, header for mails which we are sending is text/HTML and NOT text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

It's better etiquette to send  multipart/mixed and send both a plaintext and html version of the message. Are you sure that your HTML message is properly formed? Maybe yopmail/yahoo are more strict with their html rendering than other services.

You could look at a tool like Litmus which can analyze an Email message and show you what it will look like rendered in several Email clients like Thunderbird, Outlook, as well as several web mail clients like Gmail, Hotmail and more.